# Is there a built-in `take(iterable, n)` function in Python3?

Tags: python, generator, python-3.6, stopiteration

I just got bit by abusing `StopIteration` within some nested generators (using CPython 3.6.9), hadn't enabled [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) (`from __future__ import generator_stop`), and had some bad hacky code that used `next(iter(iterable))` that prematurely signaled a stop.

While PEP 479 would catch `StopIteration` from bubbling out of generators, I think I would still run into this in nested for-loops.

For now, I'm going to replace any usage of `next(iter(...))` with the following:

```py
def take(iterable, *, n):
    """
    Robustly gets the first n items from an iterable and returns them as a
    list.

    You should always use this function in lieu of `next(iter(...))`! e.g.
    instead of:

        my_first = next(iter(container))

    you should instead do:

        my_first, = take(container, n=1)

    Throws RuntimeError if the iterable cannot yield n items.
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    out = []
    for _ in range(n):
        try:
            out.append(next(iterator))
        except StopIteration:
            raise RuntimeError("Premature StopIteration encountered!")
    return out
```

My question is: Is function like this already in the stdlib for Python?

I checked through `python.org`s latest docs (for 3.9) in `itertools` and `builtins`, and the closest thing I could see was `takewhile`, but meh on that. I could also convert to a `list` or any other indexable container, but I'd like to avoid needing to iterate over everything just to access the first thing.

Comment: `islice` maybe?

Comment: You're looking for [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: Ooh, yup! That looks like it's it - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) does this (and more), without converting to a list or erroring out if not enough elements are produced.

You could write your function in terms of this one cleanly:

```
def take(iterable, *, n):
    li = list(itertools.islice(iterable, n))
    if len(li) != n:
        raise RuntimeError("too short iterable for take")
    return li
```